# How to change the bootstrap popover arrow border color without filling it?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-popover

I want to change the border-color of popover arrow.When I apply the border color,the arrow itself is filling up with the color.

I want to give only the color to the border of the arrow as for the popover body.

```
<p>Click on button to see Popover</p>

<a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover"
   data-content="This is the body of Popover"
   data-original-title="Creativity Tuts">pop
</a>

$(function () {
    $('#example').popover();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/d2fe1msb/1/)

Comment: `I want to give only the color to the border of the arrow as in the popover body.` .. I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/35909593/4763793 is the correct answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you change the`.popover.right .arrow`. So changing the `.arrow:after` will change the "fill" color for the arrow, as you see I set to gray.

```
.popover.right .arrow {
  border-right-color: aqua;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2fe1msb/2/)

Comment: according to what OP has posted your answer is correct. Only the arrow is showing colour. +1

Answer (score 4):

```
.popover.right .arrow:after {
  border-right-color: white;
}
.popover.right .arrow {
    border-right-color: red;
}
```

<kbd>[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/d2fe1msb/6/)</kbd>